# XMLHttpRequest no recupera la información que se le solicita

Tags: javascript

¿Qué ocurre? Quiero recuperar el archivo xml que devuelve la llamada pero no se conecta. Probar la ruta directamente en el navegador muestra el resultado.

La consulta se realiza al servicio que publica catastro y la intención es recuperar las coordenadas X e Y que devuelve para posteriormente hacer una búsqueda por coordenadas.

Gracias de antemano.

```
var url = "https://ovc.catastro.meh.es/ovcservweb/OVCSWLocalizacionRC/OVCCoordenadas.asmx/Consulta_CPMRC?Provincia=&Municipio=&SRS=&RC=10199A02700056";

// 1. Crea un nuevo objeto XMLHttpRequest
let xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();

// 2. Configuración: solicitud GET para la URL /article/.../load
xhr.open('GET', url);

// 3. Envía la solicitud a la red
xhr.send();

// 4. Esto se llamará después de que la respuesta se reciba
xhr.onload = function() {
  if (xhr.status != 200) { // analiza el estado HTTP de la respuesta
    alert(`Error ${xhr.status}: ${xhr.statusText}`); // ej. 404: No encontrado
  } else { // muestra el resultado
    alert(`Hecho, obtenidos ${xhr.response.length} bytes`); // Respuesta del servidor
  }
};

xhr.onprogress = function(event) {
    if (event.lengthComputable) {
      alert(`Recibidos ${event.loaded} de ${event.total} bytes`);
    } else {
      alert(`Recibidos ${event.loaded} bytes`); // sin Content-Length
    }
};

    xhr.onerror = function() {
      alert("Solicitud fallida");
    };
```

Comment: Las XMLHttpRequest están un poquito anticuadas ya... la `fetch API` es la manera *"correcta"* de realizar llamadas. Por otro lado, qué significa "No se conecta"? Añade todos los detalles y sé todo lo específico que puedas por favor, cuanto más sepamos mejor podremos ayudarte. Por otro lado, es posible que sea porque tu URL está mal formada? Digo porque hay varios campos que no tienen valor después de =, y creo que eso no es correcto: `?Provincia=&Municipio=&SRS=&`, deberías o no añadirlos, o añadir algo tas el igual.

Comment: A mi tu código sí me parece funcionar. En el código que has publicado falta cerrar la llave de `onprogress`: `}`. Con esa llave cerrada, ejecutar tu código me da el mensaje de "Recibidos 645 de 645 bytes", y luego el de "Hecho, obtenidos 643 bytes". Edito: Ah perdona, esto es activando CORS con una extensión, es probable que tu problema sea por CORS.

Comment: La ruta en la variable 'url' es correcta, está verificada con un desarrollo en c sharp. El tema es que lo tengo que llevar a javascript para visualizarlo en un mapa que trabaja con este lenguaje.

Comment: onprogress: }.  lo tengo cerrado. Se ve que al copiar y pegar falló algo. Lo pruebo en local (localhost) y el error que me da es 'Solicitud fallida'

Comment: Revisa en la consola del navegador... lo mas probable es que el request sea bloqueado por CORS